# Is it acceptable to use Google Material Design in web applications?

Tags: website-design, android, ios, material-design

We are considering using [Material Design components](https://material.io/guidelines/components) in our website, but since this is an "Android design", wouldn't it turn away iOS users?

What is the best practice? Is it wide-spread to use these components in web, or it's better to use something neutral?

Comment: Using Material Design does not make for good UX, so I would say no.

Comment: @sgroves How so?

Comment: @MiloP Flat everything == terrible for UX. Google has *always* been shockingly bad at UX design, and Material is yet another example. I would never look to Google for UX inspiration. Pretty much every other major company does it better. Google's design is the definition of "for nerds, by nerds."

Comment: @sgroves, this is opinionated. Personally, I'm tired of their [layouts](https://myaccount.google.com/privacy) "oh hey, let's make it so large that only 2 paragraphs at once can fit in a 1920x1080 screen". Not to mention the navigation maze it is, while they could just put everything in a goddamn single page. For me that bloat is the exact opposible of "nerdy".

Comment: @sgroves `Flat everything == terrible for UX`. Please do elaborate.

Comment: how on earth material design = flat everything? Do you see a "floating" button on the bottom right corner? Motions are also done in layers. I bet you've never had a quick look on the guidelines ["Material design is a three-dimensional environment containing light, material, and cast shadows."](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/environment.html). It's no different from MS's Fluent Design

Comment: @sgroves iOS design is the flat one. Material has shadows, elevation, and ripples. It's very 3D, just not quite as in-your-face as iOS's old skeumorphism.

Comment: To add to my above comment, the [page you linked](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) is even worse than my example. It requires so much scrolling it is completely unusable!

Comment: I would like to inform you about https://framework7.io/ if you use that frontend framework you can switch appearance based on device type.

Comment: "Flat everything == terrible for UX", says a @sgroves while he's on a StackOverflow site.

Comment: @GrasDouble. If that annoys you, you should see the journey planner on IrishRail.ie. No way to view all your options at once.

Comment: @transistor09 SO has some poor UX features as well. It's mostly good though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I was recently researching the use of Material Design in iOS apps and came across [this UpLabs article](https://stories.uplabs.com/should-you-use-material-design-on-ios-d740962e628d) which makes an interesting point:

> Various elements both visual and underline mechanics could certainly be incorporated into iOS apps.
>
> **However, it is important to stay true to the operating systems nature. Forcing a user to adapt or take on new sets of habits within a an app could cause great confusion.**
>
> It is important to intelligently incorporate various elements of Material Design but it is imperative not to confuse or undermine the user in the process.

For this reason, I would only consider using the Material Design guidelines **in an iOS app** where it does not conflict with the [Apple Human Interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/), *unless* the Material Design element provides a significant improvement to the end user. One such area is **movement/animation**, which in my experience is served much better by Material Design.

But when it comes to web, **there are no general HID guidelines** and as such **users have fewer expectations.**

Because they have fewer expectations, it's **perfectly acceptable to mix and match guidelines** to form the best experience for your users.

Comment: Although a website vs an App are pretty different things...

Comment: Indeed, that's what my answer is saying. Perhaps  I didn't convey it clearly enough in my final two statements :)

Comment: @SGR The OP is developing a website, so it will be the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think it's a problem. There are many applications for iOS that use Material Design. Think of all the Google applications (Youtube, GMail, etc) iOS users use on a daily basis.

You might want to consider using Material Design as a source of inspiration. Make use of their behaviours or specific elements, but also use your own research and branding.

I'm working on a product that uses Material Design elements but we also use our own colours and take inspiration from other guidelines as well. They're guidelines, not laws.

Comment: I feel the need to say that, just because other people do it, that doesn't make it right.

Comment: True. What I'm saying is that people are used to it because it has been done before by big players.

Comment: @Rob I feel the need to say that, just because other people do it, that doesn't make it wrong. ;)

Comment: You say there are "many applications" for iOS that use Material Design, but then only mention Google apps (which would be conspicuous for *not* using it). Does anyone *else* use it?

Comment: @chepner I couldn't find anything, but it looks like Google is trying to at least make it easy to use Material on iOS https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios

Answer (score 14):

Material Design is **not** "Android design", it's Google's all encompassing design "template" for both mobile and web apps. Many Google web products use Material Design like Angular (https://angular.io/) or, you know, Material Design site itself (https://material.io/guidelines/). They even have a library made specially for the web called Material Design Lite that comes with all the CSS that you need: https://getmdl.io/started/.

Comment: This is only partially true. Material design page itself does not follow its rules (not to mention other Google apps). This design is unusable for web apps under strict adherence. For example, if you look at the [Tooltip specification](https://material.io/design/components/tooltips.html#), it says that the web application should have a font size of 10dp #ffffff # 616161e6 R97 G97 B97 A0.90 All corners Rounded: 4dp. Try to click on Search on this site and wait for Tooltip. Large font and no rounded edges (like on Google or Gmail). Compliance with the specification would not be good for users.

Answer (score 3):

Material Design offers some incredible guidelines based off of user interaction and extensive user feedback. There are many sites that incorporate various features that MD promotes without actually using the full MD guidelines. To note: the difference between apps and web pages are blurring. As progressive web apps take more center stage competing with native mobile apps (web apps have many advantages), apps and web pages (web apps) will not be necessarily distinguishable as they are now.

Material Design is great for thinking about design functions of the future. Using inspiration from the material world seems like a logical progression. MD uses paper material as its inspiration. There's also room for glass, brick, wood, etc. Think outside the box. In the end, it's about usability and the ACCEPTANCE of users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact, Google has an official Material design component library for webapps, called [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org). I don't think Google doesn't intend to have anyone use it

Comment: nitpick: Polymer is a simple library that makes writing Web Components easier. The Polymer-based Material Design element collection is called [Paper elements](https://www.webcomponents.org/collection/PolymerElements/paper-elements).

Answer (score 1):

Material Design is not only design, it's an alround-everything guideline.

Even if you don't use material design components, you should use the writing guidelines for your website.

But yes, it is wide-spread. Google slowly changes all their pages into material design.

At the moment, Material Design is just the best of usability you can get. So be sure to stick to the minimum guidelines. Your users will thank you.